# Python capture RAW camera image with Android phone connected to Linux via USB

Tags: python, android, android-camera

Is there a way to capture a 14-bit raw camera image from a Python script on a Linux computer connected to an Android phone via USB (Google Pixel 4a to be specific)?
Basically like a USB Webcam, but with raw images.